# Error with System.Data.SqlClient with .NET standard

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-standard, ef-core-2.0

Please can someone tell me how to resolve this?

I am using EF Core

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I have a .NET standard class library that is hosted within service fabric

can this be resolved with assembly mappings?

I have added the System.Data.SqlClient package to both the class library and the service host

Does anyone have any ideas?

Paul

Comment: I had this problem just yesterday with Dapper, which version have you added to both projects? I found that the version I referenced in the host project (4.3.0.0) was higher than the version references in the .Net Standard project (4.2.0.0). When I downgraded then to the same all was well.

Comment: I am now trying 4.2 on both

Comment: When I set both to the same I get manifest errors on Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60?

Answer (score 0):

Just add reference to [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/2.1.0-preview1-final)

and remove `System.Data.SqlClient` package. It will be installed as dependency of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Comment: @Paul I also have a .NET standard class library that is hosted within service fabric with EF Core and that works fine

Comment: How do you ensure the output folder has the correct files?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.0 I dont see where it is looking for this version

Comment: Which version of EF Core do you use? Please cleanup solution and install that package

Comment: I was using EF Core 2.0.1 I will try to update everything to 2.0.2

Comment: Do you get issues with the dlls not being copied?

Comment: Not in a perfect way it looks like a dodgy version of the DLL got into my output folder.  I was getting round this by having copy actions in after build.  At the weekend i will try this approach from scratch as it does look nicer!